# AJAX обновление отдельного DIV

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Имеется страница с комментариями, комментарии являются отдельным блоком и должны обновляться по нажатию кнопки "комментировать" т.е отправки нового комментария, но ничего не происходит, от слова вообще ничего. Если в Ajax.BeginForm убрать "Comment", данные отправятся в БД, но не более.

```
` <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="results">
            @foreach (var t in ViewBag.Comments)
            {
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h3>@t.NameComment</h3>
                        <p>@t.Text</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comment", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
        {
            <fieldset>
                <p>Комментарий</p>
                <br />
                <p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Комментировать" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>`
```

Div с Id = result, это и есть блок с комментариями, под ним блок Ajax после вызова которого, комментарии должны обновляться.
Код из контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment, int id_post)
        {
            comment.Time = DateTime.Now;
            comment.PostId = id_post;
            comment.NameComment = User.Identity.Name;
            db.Comments.Add(comment);  
            db.SaveChanges();
            var comments = db.Comments.Where(p => p.PostId == id_post).ToList();
            return PartialView(comments);
        }
```

И само частичное представление:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebPhotoArchive.Models.Comment>
<div>
    @foreach (var t in Model)
    {
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h3>@t.NameComment</h3>
                <p>@t.Text</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: F12 в браузере, вкладка network, открывайте, смотрите, что уезжает на сервер и что приезжает.

Comment: @tym32167 Выскакивает следующая ошибка
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 POST https://localhost:44339/Home/Comment 500
Понятия не имею, что может быть не так

Comment: ну то есть у вас проблема с обработкой запроса, никак не связанная с предсталенным вами кодом

Comment: У меня два метода, GET и SET, я так понимаю, он отправляет запрос в GET, хотя должен в SET с возвращением представления
Но как это исправить и так ли это вообще?

Comment: я не очень плнимаю, о чем вы говорите. Если вы про HTTP методы, то вы используете POST - он по умолчанию для форм. Вот есть еще [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/10.3.php) асинхронной формы, но он может и не помочь ничем, так как у вас запрос к серверу выдает ошибку 500.

Comment: Я и делал по этому примеру, но как бы как видите
Можно подробнее сказать, что это может быть?

Comment: Мне кажется, вам для этого лучше поглядеть логи вашего сервера. Это может быть что угодно, предлагаю не гадать, а глянуть в логи или воспользоваться отладкой.

Comment: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error _ssl.c:1059: The handshake operation timed out>
Единственная ошибка на стороне сервера

Comment: у вас отладочный сервер на https? попробуйте http. Но, если честно, не имею ни малейшего понятия, в чем может быть проблема.